# One of two arguments fulfilled (Eather one, or another, or both)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to generate a list of students with grades **in each of these two subjects "BWIR" and "DLBKA"**. With my code I just get students that have written **both** subjects:

```
SELECT
    profil.name,
    profil.vorname,
        profil_studium.mnr,

    Kursname1.fach AS Fach1,
        Fach_BWIR.note AS Note1,
        Fach_BWIR.datum AS Datum1,

    Kursname2.fach AS Fach2,
        Fach_DLBKA.note AS Note2,
        Fach_DLBKA.datum AS Datum2,

        profil_studium.grad,
        studium.abkuerzung

FROM
    profil
    JOIN profil_studium ON profil_studium.pid = profil.id
        INNER JOIN studium ON profil_studium.studium = studium.id
    JOIN noten AS Fach_BWIR ON Fach_BWIR.sid = profil_studium.id AND Fach_BWIR.fachid = 10001466
        JOIN noten_faecher AS Kursname1 ON Kursname1.id = Fach_BWIR.fachid
    JOIN noten AS Fach_DLBKA ON Fach_DLBKA.sid = profil_studium.id AND Fach_DLBKA.fachid = 10001499
        JOIN noten_faecher AS Kursname2 ON Kursname2.id = Fach_DLBKA.fachid

WHERE
    studium.abkuerzung like "FS BAPS"

GROUP BY 
profil_studium.mnr
```

Ideally it should write "not completed" in fields "Datum" and "Note", when there has not been an exam of this student.
I guess I should use IF-cases, but I just can`t figure it out.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Your question does not make sense to anyone who does not understand the language the code is written in.  How is a "student" represented?  What is a "subject"?